# Android: Best way to let user access Preference activity?

Tags: android, mobile

I have an app in the making, and have a Preferences activity which allows the user to choose settings for the app.

What I need help with is choosing how the preference activity will be accessed by the user. Some tutorials actually have a button in the main activity labeled, for example, "preferences" which would allow the user to visit that activity.

Others (the way I have it currently) just rely on the user clicking the menu button on their phone. I read that some phones do not have a menu button anymore, and the Android team is trying to get rid of a physical navigation button requirements.

So I am a little confused, what is the general consensus on this topic? Thank you.

EDIT: Here is my current menu creation code

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Settings");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Preferences.class));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "menu button" approach. Typically, in English, the button should be called "Settings", not "Preferences", even though it manages Preferences. Silly, I know.

Regarding phones with no menu buttons:

The only phones that don't them run Android 4.0 or higher. As long as your target Android 3.0 or higher in your project build, and properly create the menu item (I'll provide a snippet if you need to know how), Android will detect that there's no hardware menu button and add an "Overflow" menu to the Action Bar.

Edit: Here's the snippet:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem buttonSettings = menu.add("Settings"); // This is a hardcoded string. When you get around to it, switch it to a localized String resource.
    buttonSettings.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_settings); // I have a custom icon for this. You can use the one in android.R.drawable, but I don't know its name right now.
    buttonSettings.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER); // This forces it to go in the overflow menu, which is preferred.
    buttonSettings.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Preferences.class); // Change YourActivity to.. well, your activity. Change Preferences to the name of your Settings activity.
            YourActivity.this.startActivity(settingsIntent);
            return false; // I honestly don't know why this should return false, but every example I've seen has it do so. So I'd leave it in.
        }
    });
return true;
}
```

The overflow menu looks like three dots, and is like a "more..." option for the Action Bar. The Android Design Guidelines say you should always put your Settings option in the overflow menu.

Hope that clears it up, anything else, feel free to ask.

Comment: I see. Well, I am testing on my very old phone (Android 2.2). So I have the menu button so the options menu appears. I just need to make sure that on Android 3.0+, my settings option won't disappear, right? It will automatically be added to the action bar where the three dots appear - hopefully. If you have the code snippet handy, I'd love to see it. Thanks Steve.

Comment: Try launching it in a 4.0 emulator. I'm not home right now, so it'll take a minute for me to get the snippet. If you want, you can send it to me, and I can test it on my 4.1 phone.

Comment: Updated my answer with the snippet.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it on the emulator and seeing what happens. I'll let you know - no rush with the snippet.

Comment: Added the snippet anyway. Also, protip: If a device has 4.0 _and_ a hardware menu button, it will hide the overflow item in the action bar, and open the overflow menu when they press the menu button.

Comment: Thanks, I posted what I currently have in my original post. Yours is quite similar, I am testing it out now to see what the differences are. I think you may be missing a return statement for the `onCreateOptionsMenu` function.

Comment: Your code didn't work for me for some reason. Quite odd. I returned false for both functions though, you think that may be a problem? I first tested the new code on my 2.2 though.

Comment: Whoops! I cut off a big chunk of the method when I copy-pasted it, and forgot the ever-important `return true;` line. You need that or it won't trigger. Updated.

Comment: Great, it works now! But it seems that it is the exact same thing as I had earlier. Hmm... What do you think of this idea: I keep the settings options available the way you and I have it coded (same essentially), but also add something in the main view that isn't in the user's view all the time as a big settings button. I was thinking of adding a tiny gear image at the bottom of the main view, which, when clicked, also brings up the settings activity. Do you think that would be a good solution? Thanks for your effort Steve!

Comment: That'll work just fine, although it's not recommended in the guidelines. Then again, it's not discouraged either, so if you think your app would benefit from it, feel free! Another idea: Since users with no menu buttons are going to see it in their action bars, do a check to see if the device has a menu button, and if it does, show the big button. If it doesn't, don't.

Comment: Oh I see! That's also a super cool idea! I have a question regarding seeing the action bar though. I tried a 4.0 simulator for my app and it wouldn't show the action bar. Maybe because it assumed that the menu buttons are present for that particular virtual device. Is there a way to test run the app on a virtual device that has no buttons?

Comment: I'm not sure how the emulator handles the menu button, I've always had a 3.0+ device to test on. :P Sorry. If you hit the menu button on the emulator though, does the overflow menu come up? I believe it should.

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. Only the traditional menu pokes out from the bottom of the screen. That's not the overflow, right? Thanks, sorry about all the questions. :)

Comment: No problem. I believe (from when I had my Galaxy S) that actually _is_ the overflow menu for devices with menu buttons. So I think it's working properly. Want me to try out the .apk to see?

Comment: I'd love to have you try it out. I just learned what exporting an apk means after fiddling around in Eclipse. Sorry, I'm very new to programming and Android especially. How do I send it to you?

Comment: Email it to steven@stevenschoen.com. Also, the Export APK feature is mainly for making production-ready APKs, as it takes out all the debug bits. If you're sending your app to another developer and not a user/app store, you can just send the APK in `yourproject/bin/`. Make sure you run the app on a device/emulator first, so it refreshes the build.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's help, especially Steven's, I have learned the following:

- For Android 3.0+, an efficient way to access my Preference activity would be by implementing the action bar
- The action bar can be added by changing the theme to Theme.Holo, which is available on 3.0+ platforms
- Since I have a phone with 2.2 on it, the Holo theme was not being found when I set it up in the manifest file, this was because my build target was 2.2
- I initially changed the minSdkVersion to 11 in order for the theme to work, but that meant I wouldn't be able to test it on my phone and no one with a version of Android less than 3.0 would be able to use my app if they wanted to
- The actual way to do it is by going into Project>Preferences>Android and setting the build target to the latest version of Android (this way, phones with higher OS versions can benefit from newer theme related changes, while the older versions remain unffected)
- One thing to watch out for when setting a higher build target is the compatibility of classes you use. Some classes may only work on the higher versions of Android, and would therefore cause your app to crash on lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do both (this is what I do). You have a settings  `virtual button` displayed on the screen and when that is clicked, the settings screen pops up. And you have the option, when the `physical button` is clicked, that the settings screen pops up.

Comment: I like that idea too, might as well make it as explicit for the user as possible to maximize their experience.

Comment: Yes, this should also make your UI and UX of your app more intuitive yielding happy users. :D

Answer (score 0):

Some who are smarter (and more aesthetically refined) than myself discuss [settings](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html) in the Android Design guide.

My generic UI design principle is:

1. Something you do all the time should be accessed with on-screen
   (content area or ActionBar action) controls.
2. Something you do once per day should be accessed off the
   top level of your menu (or on-screen only on the home screen).
3. Something you do seldomly (like changing
   user preferences) can be buried as deep in the menu hierarchy as you
   want.  :-)

In practice, I typically expect Settings to be in the first Overflow level from the home Activity.

Comment: Hey, I like that concept. I think I will follow those guidelines from now on. I'm just not too familiar with the action bar simply because I only have an Android 2.2 phone. I will start experimenting with it on a simulator. Thanks.

Comment: Please consider looking at the ActionBarCompat sample and  ActionBarSherlock.  It's great when you can have a unified UX that covers the newest hotness and brings the legacy users along for the ride.